# Angle proof question.

Tags: proof-verification

[image]

Hi, I just want to know if my proof seems ok.

So we can begin with :

1 degrees = 1+1/9 grads

we multiply by x to generalize

x degrees= x+x/9 grads

now, we take x degrees and multiply it by 60 minutes to know how many minutes it makes.We also do the same with x+x/9 grads but we multiply it by a 100 minutes. After, we put this form :

60x degrees/(100x+100x/9) grads

we simplify it :

60x/(1000x/9)grads

60x * 9/1000x

We cancel and simplify

3*9/50

Which finally gives us 27/50 for any 'x'.

Does this seem correct ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your argument doesn't look *wrong* as such (though I haven't checked it in details), but it does make it rather difficult to see the forest for trees since you start writing about an unknown angle $x$ from the beginning. That means that you never get to note the fundamental underlying fact:

**27 ordinary minutes of arc equals 50 "centesimal minutes"**

which can be seen by noting that both are exactly 1/200 of a right angle (and, as Euclid says, all right angles are equal).

Once you've seen that, consider an arbitrary angle $\theta$. There are *some* number $y$ (rational or irrational) of 200ths of a right angle in $\theta$, so $\theta$ is simultaneously $27y$ minutes of arc and $50y$ centesimal minutes. The ratio between these is $\frac{27y}{50y} = \frac{27}{50}$.

---

If this feels too much like "cheating" because it assumes that the ratio is already known (which it is! it's given to you by the problem statement!), then you could also start by measuring in right angles instead, and get the ratio $\frac{5400}{10000}$ which simplifies algebraically to $\frac{27}{50}$.